# How to get information using css selector and store it variable

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to verify the values from a register by using a css selector

```
[FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "#grid_cases > table > tbody")]
private IWebElement CaseListGrid;
```

I have to return the WebElements value and store it to string

```
public List<CaseListEntry> GetCaseListEntries()
{
    CaseListGrid.
    return null;         
}
```

Comment: By mentioning `WebElements value`, which `value` are you pointing towards? Needless to say, `Attributes` will have a related `value`.

Comment: Give us your HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the text from your CaseListGrid element by using the following:

```
CaseListGrid.Text;
```

But you are retrieving a tbody, which probably doesn't have any text in it.

After you retrieved the CaseListGrid element, you could do something like this to retrieve all `td` tags *inside* the tbody.

```
CaseListGrid.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));
```

After that, loop over the elements and retrieve the text:

```
public List<CaseListEntry> GetCaseListEntries()
{
    var elements = CaseListGrid.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));
    var listEntries = new List<CaseListEntry>();

    foreach (var element in elements)
    {
        var text = element.Text;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
            listEntries.Add(new CaseListEntry(text)); // I don't know what kind of class CaseListEntry is, so this is pseudo code
    }

    return listEntries;         
}
```

Comment: Non-invocable member

Comment: Ah I noticed I made a mistake, it should be `.Text` instead of `.Text()`. I modified my answer.

Comment: This can be condensed using LINQ. Something like `return CaseListGrid.FindElements(By.TagName("td")).Where(e => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Text)).Select(e => new CaseListEntry(e.Text));` which should return you an `IEnumerable<CaseListEntry>`, as an example

Comment: @Arran Thanks you very much it works , But I have to store as DateTime instead of string, How can i change string to datetime

Comment: @MutuSteinnn You'd have to parse it, so `DateTime.Parse(e.Text);`

Comment: @Arran how can i use parse here,   My code is [Register = CaseEntryTds.ElementAt(2).Text,]

Comment: @MutuSteinnn `Register = DateTime.Parse(CaseEntryTds.ElementAt(2).Text),`

Comment: @Arran  Thank you very much!! ,it work's, Happy weekend

Answer (score 0):

It works

```
 var CaseGridTrs = CaseListGrid.FindElements(By.XPath(".//tr"));
        var entryList = CaseGridTrs.Select(x => 
        {
            var CaseEntryTds = x.FindElements(By.XPath(".//td"));
            return new CaseListEntry
            {                                     Register = CaseEntryTds.ElementAt(0).FindElement(By.XPath(".//a")).Text,
```